# How to use operator overloading to simplify the addition of two fractions?

Tags: c++

I need use operator overloading to simplify the addition of two fractions. I  want to get minimalist result. I use twice euclidean algorithm, the first time, I get the multiple of the denominator. the second time, I want to simplify fraction.
Like these two fractions

```
1 10
1 10
```

result:

```
1 5
```

It adds two Numbers and simplifies them

The main code snippet:

```cpp
Fraction operator+(const Fraction &a1, const Fraction &a2) {

    int max, min, temp_1 , temp_2, n, m, sum, max_1, min_1, temp_3 ;
    if (a1.numerator < a2.numerator) {
        max = a2.numerator;
        min = a1.numerator;
    } else {
        max = a1.numerator;
        min = a2.numerator;
    }
    //euclidean algorithm 
    while (max % min != 0) {
        temp_1 = max % min;
        max = min;
        min = temp_1;
    }
    //Least common multiple
    temp_2 = max * min / temp_1;

    n = temp_2 / a1.numerator * a1.denominator;
    m = temp_2 / a2.numerator * a2.denominator;
    sum = n + m;
    if (sum > temp_2) {
        max_1 = sum;
        min_1 = temp_2;
    } else {
        max_1 = temp_2;
        min_1 = sum;
    }
    //euclidean algorithm 
    while (max_1 % min_1 != 0) {
        temp_3 = max_1 % min_1;
        max_1 = min_1;
        min_1 = temp_3;
    }
    sum = sum / temp_3;
    temp_2 = temp_2 / temp_3;
    return Fraction(sum, temp_2);
}
```

The complete code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Fraction {
private:

    int numerator, denominator;
public:
    Fraction(int numerator1=0, int denominator1=0) : numerator(numerator1), denominator(denominator1) {}
    void show() const; //Output all data
    friend Fraction operator+(const Fraction &a1, const Fraction &a2);
};
void Fraction::show() const {
    cout << "x/y= " << numerator << " / " << denominator << endl;
}
Fraction operator+(const Fraction &a1, const Fraction &a2) {

    int max, min, temp_1 , temp_2, n, m, sum, max_1, min_1, temp_3 ;
    if (a1.numerator < a2.numerator) {
        max = a2.numerator;
        min = a1.numerator;
    } else {
        max = a1.numerator;
        min = a2.numerator;
    }
    //euclidean algorithm 
    while (max % min != 0) {
        temp_1 = max % min;
        max = min;
        min = temp_1;
    }
    //Least common multiple
    temp_2 = max * min / temp_1;

    n = temp_2 / a1.numerator * a1.denominator;
    m = temp_2 / a2.numerator * a2.denominator;
    sum = n + m;
    if (sum > temp_2) {
        max_1 = sum;
        min_1 = temp_2;
    } else {
        max_1 = temp_2;
        min_1 = sum;
    }
    //euclidean algorithm 
    while (max_1 % min_1 != 0) {
        temp_3 = max_1 % min_1;
        max_1 = min_1;
        min_1 = temp_3;
    }
    sum = sum / temp_3;
    temp_2 = temp_2 / temp_3;
    return Fraction(sum, temp_2);
}
int main() {
    Fraction a1(1 ,5);
    Fraction a2(3, 5);
    Fraction a;
    cout << "a1: ";
    a1.show();
    cout << "a2: ";
    a2.show();
    cout << "a: " ;
    a = a1 + a2;
    a.show();

}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. "Clion doesn't return anything"? What is Clion? Is this a build-time error or a run-time error? If it' a run-time error, what result do you expect and what result do you get? Also, see [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Sorry, I've corrected it. Clion is a IDE, I want to use operator overloading to simplify the addition of two fractions, I did`t get result.

Comment: If the code is working take it to https://codereview.stackexchange.com for a review.

Comment: an alternative way would be to factorize numerator and denominator and call std::set_intersection/set_difference on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That addition is far, far too complicated.
(That it's almost impossible to tell what could be wrong with what should be a very simple arithmetic operation is a strong indicator about that.)

Start with extracting Euclides into a function:

```
int gcd(int a, int b)
{
    if (a < b)
        return gcd(b, a);
    while (b != 0) {
        int t = b;
        b = a % b;
        a = t;
    }
    return a;
}
```

(Or use `std::gcd`, if you are C++17-modern.)

Then rewrite the constructor to do simplification (you don't want to force the user of your class to worry about that):

```
Fraction(int numerator1=0, int denominator1=1) 
{
    int divisor = gcd(numerator1, denominator1);
    numerator = numerator1 / divisor;
    denominator = denominator1 / divisor;   
}
```

You should also let the default denominator be 1, since division by zero is undefined.
Invalid fractions by default is a bad idea.

With this, addition becomes almost trivial:

```
Fraction operator+(const Fraction &a1, const Fraction &a2) {
    int numerator = a1.numerator * a2.denominator + a2.numerator * a1.denominator;
    int denominator = a1.denominator * a2.denominator;
    return Fraction(numerator, denominator);
}
```

Comment: You could use `std::gcd`

Comment: Thank you, you give me other idea. First, I add it. Then, I simplify it.

Comment: @Kerndog73 I'm old enough to not have noticed that it exists.

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear what problem you're having, so I'll assume by "didn't get result" that you didn't get the expected result.

One source of error is that `temp_1` can be uninitialized when used in the Least common multiple calculation.  (This will happen if `max` is a multiple of `min`, and in your specific test because `min` is 1.)  The compiler can issue a warning for this if the warning level is high enough.

Another problem is that your code does not handle a zero fraction.  It also seems like the one parameter constructor for `Fraction` (where the denominator defaults to 0) is wrong, and the denominator should be 1.

Answer (score 1):

I failed to understand use of Euclidean algorithm in your code. Also use variables like hcf, lcm instead of temp1 or temp2 to clarify your intend. Here is a snippet of calculating hcf and lcm of the denominators using Euclid theorem.

```
Fraction operator+(const Fraction &a1, const Fraction &a2)
{
    int max, min, hcf, lcm, num;

    if (a1.denominator < a2.denominator) {
        max = a2.denominator;
        min = a1.denominator;
    }
    else {
        max = a1.denominator;
        min = a2.denominator;
    }

        //euclidean algorithm 
        if (max % min == 0)
        {
            hcf = min;
        }
        else
        {
            while (max % min != 0) {
                hcf = max % min;
                max = min;
                min = hcf;
            }
        }

        lcm = (a1.denominator * a2.denominator) / hcf;

        num = a1.numerator * lcm / a1.denominator + a2.numerator * lcm / a2.denominator;

        return Fraction(num, lcm);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I may be descripe my problem,  the first time, I get the multiple of the denominator. the second time, I want to simplify fraction. So, I use twice euclidean algorithm. I think your code clear and understandable, I get some idea, First, I add it. Then, I simplify it.